# Proplem with url using in Casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have problem with the url of my website that I'm doing on it with casperjs.I want to get title and test the class or id that have in this page,and set the value to textbox in this website by using casperjs.

```
//var url = 'https://www.google.com.kh/';
//this url below it is not work with my code if the url above it work normal
var url = 'https://teleservices.paris.fr/etatcivil/jsp/site/RunStandaloneApp.jsp?page=formengine&form=naissance';

var casper = require('casper').create();
    casper.start(url, function() {
            this.echo(url);

            this.echo("start page...");

    });
    casper.then(function(){
        this.wait(1000,function(){
            this.echo('Page: ' + this.getTitle());
            });

    }),
    casper.then(function() {
             if(this.exists("div.job-search-box-text")){
                    this.echo("this is id found");
                }
               else{
                    this.echo("no ID found");
                }

    }),
    casper.then(function(){
        this.wait(1000,function(){
            this.fillSelectors('form', {

                    'input[name="title"]' : "12"
            });
            this.capture('result.png');
            });

});


casper.run();
```

I have the problem with this url when I set the `var url = 'https://teleservices.paris.fr/etatcivil/jsp/site/RunStandaloneApp.jsp?page=formengine&form=naissance'; my result code can not display the title of the web page,can not get the each id or class in this webpage,can not capture....I'm stuck with this anyone have solution , I have tried it for long time,please help me, thanks.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using casperjs 1.0.2 on OSX mavericks and I don't have problem to display the title.
You check if div.job-search-box-text exists but it does not exists in the two cases.
And the fillSelectors code which output error : there is no input field with a name title.

here is the output for the url https://www.google.com.kh/

```
https://www.google.com.kh/
start page...
Page: Google
no ID found
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.fillSelectors('form',     {'input[name="title"]' : "12"})')
/Users/jeff/Downloads/code/automation/casperjs-1.0.3/scripts/test.js:24
/Users/jeff/Downloads/code/automation/casperjs-1.0.3:1677 in _check
```

here is the output for the url https://www.google.com.kh/

```
https://teleservices.paris.fr/etatcivil/jsp/site/RunStandaloneApp.jsp?page=formengine&form=naissance
start page...
Page: Acte de naissance
no ID found
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.fillSelectors('form', {'input[name="title"]' : "12"})')
/Users/jeff/Downloads/code/automation/casperjs-1.0.3/scripts/test.js:24
/Users/jeff/Downloads/code/automation/casperjs-1.0.3:1677 in _check
```

Comment: The TypeError is because fillSelectors was introduced in Casper 1.1 http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillselectors

Answer (score 1):

Wow - I can't figure out that is going on here. I got the code to work but I wasn't able to figure out exactly what fixed it.

There are a few oddities with the site, sometimes an image will 404 for me and I noticed an odd url structure. Note the //css/

https://teleservices.paris.fr/etatcivil//css/plugins/images/local/skin/plugins/etatcivil/left-first-srub.gif

I wish there was some key lesson to give you here - I am sure there is but I don't know it :)

```
var url = "https://teleservices.paris.fr/etatcivil/jsp/site/RunStandaloneApp.jsp?page=formengine&form=naissance";

var casper = require('casper').create({
    logLevel:"debug",
    verbose: true,
    waitTimeout: 6000
});



casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1)');

casper.start(url, function() {
    this.echo(url);
    this.echo("start page...");
});

casper.waitForSelector('#formengine-menu', function() {
    this.echo('Page: ' + this.getTitle());

});

casper.then(function() {
    if(this.exists("#naissancelieuEtDate")){    this.echo("Form naissancelieuEtDate exists");   }
    else{   this.echo("no ID found");   }
});

casper.then(function(){

    this.fill('#naissancelieuEtDate', {
            'dateActeJour' : "12"
    });
    this.capture('result.png');

 });
```

casper.run();